# Error while printing the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I created the linked list to store employee id and name.

When I tried to print it, it shows only id not an employee name and i also want to exit the program when the user enter -1 and not asking the name its should simply exit the program and display the id and name i am currently using devC++ for compiling my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *create()
{
    struct node *p, *r, *n;
    int s, k;
    char name[20];
    s = sizeof(struct node);
    printf("Linked List\n");
    printf("Enter id:");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", name);
    p = r = NULL;
    while(k!=-1)
    {
        n = (struct node *)malloc(s);
        n->id = k;
        n->next = NULL;
        if(r == NULL)
            r = n;
        else
            p->next=n;
        p=n;
        printf("Enter the Id or-1 to stop:");
        scanf("%d", &k);
        printf("Enter the name ");
        scanf("%s", name);
    }
    return(r);      
}

void display(struct node *r)
{
     printf("\nId             Name \n");
     while(r != NULL)
     {
         printf("\n %d", r->id);
         printf("\n %s", r->name);
         r = r->next;    
     }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = create();
    display(ptr);
}
```

Comment: you don't store the read in name...

Comment: Aside: Your program flow is strange in that it makes the user input a name after entering the exit code, -1.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Say you wish to create list such as 1->2->NULL. when it comes to inserting 2, you are doing p->next=n; where p is NULL !

Comment: i tried to save name n->name=name but it shows error

Comment: fixed the indentation

Comment: you need to use [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or something similar to copy a string.

Comment: @AditiRawat `p` won't be `NULL` as in the previous iteration of the loop it gets assigned with the value of `n`

Comment: Thanks the lot it solves my issues

Comment: @AditiRawat only the formatting has been edited - the logic hasn't changed

Comment: @Chris Turner I thought p=n was a part of the else block. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You actually read in the `name` variable, but you don't move it in your structure.
That said, you could directly read into the structure you allocate, but the tricky part is taking care of not overflowding your buffer when the user input is too big (more than 19 chars).

This could look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *create(void) {
    struct node *p, *r;
    printf("Linked List\n");
    p = r = NULL;
    while (1) {
        int id;
        printf("Enter the Id or-1 to stop:");
        scanf("%d", &id);

        if (id == -1)
            break; // user asked to leave

        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
        // if (n == NULL) exit(-1); as you prefere...
        n->id = id;
        printf("Enter the name ");
        // careful of buffer overflow here
        scanf("%19s%*[^\n]", n->name);
        n->next = NULL;

        if (r == NULL)
            r = n;
        else
            p->next = n;
        p = n;
    }
    return r;
}

void delete(struct node *r) {
    while (r != NULL) {
        struct node *n = r;
        r = r->next;
        free(n);
    }
}

void display(const struct node *r) {
    printf("\nId             Name \n");
    while (r != NULL) {
        printf("%d         %s\n", r->id, r->name);
        r = r->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct node *ptr = create();
    display(ptr);
    delete(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

As a bonus, I also added the free part so that you don't leak.